# Displaying File Name from an directory using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I have the following code for displaying file names in a given directory

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('folder/', function (err, files) 
{
  if (err)
    throw err;
  for (var index in files)
    {
      console.log(files[index]);
    }
});
```

Here how can I store all the file names in an array after the completion of for loop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array and use the `push()` method.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('.', function (err, files) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var filenames = [];
  for (var index in files) {
    console.log(files[index]);
    filenames.push(files[index]);
  }

  // do something with "filenames"
  // ['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js']
});
```